# Identifying end and start of input and saving them as variables

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for something in JS that could help me identify when a set of numbers begins and ends(by a space or other character that is not a number or letter).

For example: let's say the user inputs - `2424+345` (yes I'm building a calculator). I want to identify when the number starts and ends (ends when the `+` sign starts). Then it saves it as a variable for later use and continues reading the second set of numbers and assigns it to a variable as well. I can loop through the input, but what I don't know is how to write the rule that does all the checking and assigning.

`Regex` seems to be the way to go, but I have very little experience with it (have done some simple form validation with it).

Comment: What if the minus sign is part of the number, e.g., if the user types `35 / -7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the first number in a string, the regular expression would be `/^\d+/`, so for instance:

```
var str = "2424+345";
var match = /^\d+/.exec(str);
if (match) {
    // match[0] now contains "2424"
}
```

Put that in a loop, consuming the operators...

Comment: +1 - My regex-foo is'nt that good, but this seems like a better idea.